# is there an alternative to VoIP push when building the app for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, ios13, xcode11

Have tried given payload with all the options mentioned at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc

Tried below payload by sending it after every 20 minutes.

```
  "aps":{
    "apns-priority":5,
    "content-available":1,
    "apns-push-type":"background",
    "apns-topic":"com.yourdomain.appname",
    "sound":""
  },
  "Testing":100
}
```

Received notification and observed given logs in console app.

```
Received incoming message on topic com.yourdomain.appname at priority 10
Received remote notification request 8FB5-8CC5 [ hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 pushType: Alert]
Deliver push notification 8FB5-8CC5
```

But app was not launched.

Please help me by providing the alternate solution to launch app when terminated by system/user.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If the app is terminated by the user then you cannot receive silent push notifications and execute code.

Comment: @Paulw11 actually there is a number of apps that do something to awake app killed by the user. App is awaken in the background and executes some code. But how?

Comment: Your app will not receive silent push notifications if terminated by the user, if the battery level is low (<20%), and possibly other conditions apple may come up with. Apps wake up for location, regions, background refresh and other events, but not just because the developer feels like it, Personally, I wouldn't be using an iPhone otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use background Push with Legacy Push Token.

From 1st August VoIP Push is only for VoIP incoming calls and must be integrated by CallKIt, otherwise after 3 such consecutive VoIP push if app fail to open CallKit that device won't receive any further push.